# Слайдер изображений (картинки из массива ссылок) + Glide библиотека

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-imageview, android-viewpager

Поставил библиотеку Glide, вроде бы все работает.

Пытаюсь сделать viewPager, который будет пролистывать картинки из моего массива ссылок (подгружаются в imageView через Glide).

**Есть адаптер:**

```
package com.handidevelop.myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ArrayList<String> URLs;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> URLs)
    {
        this.URLs = URLs;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return URLs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)o);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);

        String url = URLs.get(position);
        textView.setText("Image: " + position);

        Glide.with(ctx).load("http://dota2.ru"+url+".jpg").into(imageView);

        Toast.makeText(ctx,
                "Position :"+position+"  ListItem : " +url , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        container.addView(item_view);

        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

**swipe_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

В основном активити:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    //private EditText edit_text;
    //private ImageView imageView1;
    private ListView listView1;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        HTMLGet htm = new HTMLGet();
        htm.execute("http://dota2.ru/memes/");
        String all = null;
        try {
            all = htm.get();
        } catch(Exception ie) {}

        ArrayList<String> URLs = XMLWork.getURLs(all);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, URLs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

В итоге на viewPager главной формы ничего ровным счетом не выводит, не понимаю почему так происходит.

Comment: `swipe_layout.xml` приведен не полностью, т. к. так бы оно не скомпилировалось.